# How can I rerun a program with gdb until a segmentation fault occurs?

Tags: gdb

My program has a segmentation fault problem, but it faults rarely(once in 20 times or more), and to debug it in GDB, I need to manually rerun the program until the segmentation fault occurs (during a half day of reruns only once it fails :( ).

So the questions is, is there any way to tell the GDB to rerun program until some segfault?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Put a breakpoint at the exit of your program that triggers the `run` command, and don't forget `set pagination off`.  Information on settings commands is available in the [Breakpoint Command Lists](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Break-Commands.html#Break-Commands) section of the gdb documentation.  In short:

```
set pagination off
break _exit
commands
run
end
```

After the `commands` line you'll see that the next two lines are being entered as the command to execute when the breakpoint is reached.

Comment: Put a breakpoint at exit function, "break exit commands run end" :)

Comment: This works in my case, but it runs 5 times and then I have to press return to continue, and runs another 5 times. Is this usual?

Comment: the answer seems to be "set pagination off" in gdb

Comment: What is the equivalent for lldb?

Comment: I found this for lldb, but it's not a direct replacement https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/lldb/trunk/utils/test/run-until-faulted.py.  For example, hitting Ctrl-C exits completely.

Comment: @montefuscolo

This will run and exit if the subprocess exits cleanly, and dump you into an interactive lldb if it segfaults:


    "lldb -o run -b /path/to/binary -- args args args"

so you can wrap it in a shell loop to get the desired effect.

    "while lldb -o run -b /path/to/binary -- args args args; do sleep 1; done"

Comment: Note that the line `commands` is a keyword, not a placeholder for your commands! It is a context-sensitive keyword, so it refers to the last breakpoint that was set during that gdb session. You literally just type `commands` on a line by itself, and gdb magically understands that you want to add commands to the breakpoint. This is *highly* non-intuitive. Fortunately there is a prompt in gdb to guide the remaining steps.

Answer (score 10):

```
(gdb) set pagination off
(gdb) break exit
(gdb) commands
>run
>end
(gdb) run
```