# How to re-run program in GDB several times?

Tags: debugging, gdb

I have a program which fails sporadically, but with the same error. To debug it I'd like to run it under GDB until it fails, set breakpoints and re-run it.
what do I do:

```
gdb --args /path/to/program <program args>
```

But I can't find anywhere how do I tell GDB "run this program 100 times" for example.

Comment: Rename `main()` to `my_program()` and add a `int main()` that calls `my_program()` 100 times? (I know this might break for some of the trickier programs that do things with `atexit()` etc., but it might serve as a workaround.)

Comment: write a bash or dos script to run it 100 times.

Comment: @Gregg this appears to be the only solution

Comment: I would suggest gdb scripts. See this question for instance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748501/what-are-the-best-ways-to-automate-a-gdb-debugging-session

Comment: Is there any terminating condition or do you want to run the program exactly 100 times?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I don't need to re-run the program exactly N times, but until certain event occurs, for example sigsegv. In my case it occurs once per 80-100 runs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I rerun a program with gdb until a segmentation fault occurs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545763/how-can-i-rerun-a-program-with-gdb-until-a-segmentation-fault-occurs)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This gdb script will run the program 100 times, or until it receives a signal. `$_siginfo` is non-void if the program is stopped due to a signal, and is void if the program exited. As far as I can tell, *any* stop of the process, including breakpoints, watchpoints, and single-stepping, will set `$_siginfo` to something.

```
set $n = 100
while $n-- > 0
  printf "starting program\n"
  run
  if $_siginfo
    printf "Received signal %d, stopping\n", $_siginfo.si_signo
    loop_break
  else
    printf "program exited\n"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 15):

The simplest solution I can think of is to run program in infinite while loop until it fails or you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to break the loop.

```
(gdb) while 1
 >run
 >end
```