# GDB: Re-run program until it faults, answering prompts along the way

Tags: c, linux, debugging, gdb, gdbinit

## Issue

---

I am attempting to have [gdb](/questions/tagged/gdb) automatically debug a [c](/questions/tagged/c) program that I am reviewing, where there is a small, but real chance (ie: one in `10,000` chance) of a crash occurring due to a known bug. I contend with another engineer that it's serious enough to address, so I need to actually cause the crash to occur to justify putting the time into fixing it. To speed up testing, I plan to write a script to have the application run in GDB, for days if need be, until it crashes.

---

## Prior Research

---

[I've found out how to run simple applications through GDB until segfaulting via a separate answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6546674/1022889), but I need to extend the problem a bit. So, I know I can run a program repeatedly until it crashes via:

---

```
set pagination off
break exit
commands
run
end
```

---

## Problem

---

What I need to do is figure out how to issue certain commands. After my program runs for a few seconds, it will ask the user to enter (via `stdin`) a number in the range of `[0,100]`, and hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. I would like it to enter `0`,<kbd>ENTER</kbd>, on the first iteration, `1`,<kbd>ENTER</kbd>, on the second iteration, etc. I realize this would b a lot easier if I added command-line arguments to the application, but I'm not allowed to change it at this time, and must rely on the interactive mode of operation it provides.

---

## Question

---

**How would I create a command to automatically generate these keystrokes/patterns with GDB**? I'm guessing I could write some sort of `GDBINIT` script, but I mostly use GDB interactively for getting backtraces, analyzing memory, etc, and am not overly familiar with automating tasks like these.

Thank you.

Comment: Please thank out :)

Comment: If the program just reads from `stdin`, why don't you just redirect a file to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you program reads its input from `stdin`, your task is straightforward. Simply create your input file as follows:

```
1
2
3
...
```

Then, your gdb command sequence changes its `run` phase to include the input file (say `input.txt`):

```
set pagination off
break exit
commands
run < input.txt
end
```

Comment: Thank you. One last question: is it possible to have a conditional change to the input? ie: if a certain line of text appears in the console output of the program, to start using a different set of input data, or just jump to `100` as the input value? Additionally, can I tell it to keep re-using input.txt?

Comment: That's far harder. Here you would have to have an intelligent script communicating with the program to both provide the input and read the output

Comment: Thanks again. This helped a lot!