# How can I keep running a debug configuration in eclipse until I get a segfault?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, eclipse-cdt

I have a C++ program that segfaults occasionally. The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6546674/1016861) to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6545763/1016861) provides a way to make GDB run my program over and over until it catches the segfault.

However, navigating my program via GDB has been a pain and I would like to do this using the Eclipse debugger. I have successfully created a debug configuration that runs my program.

Is there a way to make Eclipse keep running this debug configuration until a segfault (or other error) occurs?

I thought I may be able to do it by providing a GDB command file in the debug configuration that would set a break point at the program's exit and then command GDB to rerun the program.

Attempted GDB command file:

```
break exit
run
end
```

But using this GDB command file results in the following error when I attempt to start a debugging session:

```
Error in final launch sequence
Failed to execute MI command:
source /home/matt/gdb-loop
Error message from debugger back end:
/home/matt/gdb-loop:2: Error in sourced command file:\nNo executable file specified.\nUse the "file" or "exec-file" command.
/home/matt/gdb-loop:2: Error in sourced command file:\nNo executable file specified.\nUse the "file" or "exec-file" command.
```

So it seems like the command for the program I am debugging gets overridden when I modify the GDB command file being used.

FYI: Running Eclipse Neon (4.6.0 build 20160613-1800) on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Are you able to run the debugger at all?

Comment: Not when I try changing the GDB command file to the contents in my post. But if I keep it to the default it runs just fine.